# Having noise problem designing a stereo amplifier with TDA2030

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

I have successfully made a mono TDA2030 amplifier using a single-power-supply which worked flawlessly without any noise.

When I tried to design a stereo circuit with two TDA 2030 ICs, both of the speakers have a lot of noise. Here is the circuit I have tried:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTo1n4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Please note that both TDA 2030 circuits given above are connected to a 12-0 volt DC (non-center-tapped transformer with full bridge rectifier)  not 12-0-12.

Where did I make a mistake? Please point out the mistake with proper schematic and markings also please describe the issue.

Comment: What happens if you use separate 12V supplies, with a common ground? What happens if you use a different input source? What **kind** of noise do you hear?

Comment: You are asking for trouble not supplying + and - supply voltages (unless you are extremely careful with the negative voltage power routing and know exactly what you are doing).

Comment: Please add your PSU decoupling to the schematic.

Comment: Did you use the same TRS plug in both cases, or did you have to re-wire it to use stereo?

Comment: bypass and decoupling on 12vdc??

Comment: Download the data sheet and read it. You will find it is very susceptible to feedback and that the output needs to have a filter network. Pay attention to the section labeled practical considerations especially decoupling. If the power supply is not well decoupled it will feed back by that route as well. There are DC bias requirements you are not meeting. Try again but use there schematic and add more decoupling.

Comment: That. Also, your power supply might simply not be able to reliably supply enough current for *two* amplifiers.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson , Same the noise exists yet...

Comment: @Andy Aka please friend be a little clear to me, haven't been able to understand that riddle...

Comment: @Pete W please share your schematic, it's a bit hard for me to understand in this way

Comment: You are using the negative supply rail as also your signal ground reference and that means the signal ground reference rail is also carry large speaker currents. That means, trouble unless you know how to properly stop signal tracks carrying speaker currents. With + and - supplies, signal ground is isolated from a rail that carries speaker currents much more easily.

Comment: @Andrew Morton , audio input female socket,  Right speaker pin of the socket connected to 1st opamp and Left speaker pin of the socket connected to 2nd opamp and Audio ground is connected to power (-ve) ground

Comment: @Andy Aka, well getting it a little but would u mind if I ask for the schematic? It would be better for me to understand thanks... Well u have previously helped me in my previous question with a schematic which didn't take long to understand

Comment: The data sheet provides an example.

Comment: @Subha Jeet Sikdar -- I mean capacitors to stiffen the supply voltage to each active device

Comment: _"So, where did I make a mistake?"_ some aspects of your circuit are not good, but your 'mistake' may actually be in the construction. Please show us a photo of the setup, showing all wiring.

Comment: @Andy Aka, i actually am not been able to understand the messy schematic drawn in the data sheet that's why I am asking you to give a schematic and mark it with red inks or something like that which will make it easier to understand

Comment: I'm not sure what messy schematic you refer to @SubhaJeetSikdar. You need to apply power to your circuit at precisely the right points i.e. directly to the pin 3 and not have anything connecting between pin 3 and the return speaker wire. Maybe you should do as requested by Bruce Abbott above also.

Comment: @Pete W yes, i ve attached a capacitor with the power pin of each ic and noise is slightly gone but not fully yet !!! 90% clear and 10% noise now, maybe I should keep increasing capacitance of those capacitors...

Comment: The TDA2030 and TDA2030A are very old and are not made anymore. If yours fails then a replacement is not available. Use a newer amplifier IC instead. If the supply is 12VDC with good filtering then the output power without clipping is only about 1.5W into 8 ohms.